# geom_text two colors in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a `ggplot` with a `geom_text()`:

```
geom_text(y = 4, aes(label = text))
```

The variable text has the following format:

```
number1-number2
```

I want to know if it is possible to define a color for the number1 and another color for number2 (example: red and green color)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is if you have for example the label texts of number1 and number2 as separate columns in the data frame:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + geom_text(label=data[,3], color="red", vjust=0) + geom_text(label=data[,4], color="blue", vjust=1)
```

Comment: Yes I can do that, but in the plot the text must be in the same line

Answer (score 1):

You may also try `annotate`:

```
# data for plot
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)

# data for annotation
no1 <- "number1"
no2 <- "number1"
x_annot <- 4
y_annot <- 5
dodge <- 0.3

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = c(x_annot - dodge, x_annot, x_annot + dodge), y = y_annot,
           label = c(no1, "-", no2),
           col = c("red", "black", "green")) + 
theme_classic()
```

I defined the labels and positions outside the `annotate` call, which possibly makes it easier to generate these variables more dynamically, e.g. if "number1" in fact could be calculated from the original data set, or positions be based on range of x and y.