# How to set different font color of labels in pie chart using ggplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

The number and the percentage of the items were used for the labels in the pie chart, how to set the number and percentage using different color? Now I paste them into one string, if use them seperately, I think I can set them to different color, however the position is very hard to adjust.

This is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(cowplot)

#data 
c_title<-data.frame(titles=c("Prof", "Asso Prof","Lecture","Primary"),
                    nums=c(20,25,10,5))
c_title$titles<-factor(c_title$titles,levels = c("Primary","Lecture", "Asso Prof","Prof"))
c_title$Percentage<-sprintf("%.1f",c_title$nums/sum(c_title$nums)*100) #percengate
c_title$pie_text<- paste(c_title$Percentage,"%",sep="") #percengate%
c_title$num_p<-paste(c_title$nums,c_title$pie_text,sep="\n")
#plot
ggplot(data = c_title, aes(x = "", y = nums, fill = titles)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",width = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = num_p), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),color="red") +
  #  geom_text(aes(label = nums), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.3))+
  coord_polar(theta = "y",direction = -1)+
  labs(x ="", y = "", title = "") +  #
  theme(axis.line = element_blank())+ #remove the axis
  theme(axis.ticks =  element_blank(),axis.text = element_blank(),
        legend.position=c(0.2,0),legend.justification=c(0,1)) +#remove the -
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title = NULL,nrow=1)) #remove title of legend
```

[The chart I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKHAb.png)
[The chart I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2Q7C.png)

Comment: do you mean each label separate? Or the number in black and the percentage in red for example?

Comment: Exactly. Number in black and percentage in red.

Comment: Have a look at the second answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804234/geom-text-two-colors-in-r He is using `annotate` where you can actually do something like this.

Comment: I ues two annotate or geom_text function, but it looks ugly

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what about using two independent `geom_text` and also using absolute positions on the y axis? Something like

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(cowplot)

c_title<-data.frame(titles=c("Prof", "Asso Prof","Lecture","Primary"),
                    nums=c(20,25,10,5))
c_title$titles<-factor(c_title$titles,levels = c("Primary","Lecture", "Asso Prof","Prof"))
c_title$Percentage<-sprintf("%.1f",c_title$nums/sum(c_title$nums)*100) #percengate
c_title$pie_text<- paste(c_title$Percentage,"%",sep="") #percengate%
c_title$num_p<-paste(c_title$nums,c_title$pie_text,sep="\n")
c_title$cumsum <- cumsum(c_title$nums)-c_title$nums/2
#plot
ggplot(data = c_title, aes(x = "", y = nums, fill = titles)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",width = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = nums, y=cumsum, x=0.95),color="red") +
  geom_text(aes(label = pie_text, y=cumsum, x=1.05),color="black") +
  #  geom_text(aes(label = nums), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.3))+
  coord_polar(theta = "y",direction = -1)+
  labs(x ="", y = "", title = "") +  #
  theme(axis.line = element_blank())+ #remove the axis
  theme(axis.ticks =  element_blank(),axis.text = element_blank(),
        legend.position=c(0.2,0),legend.justification=c(0,1)) +#remove the -
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title = NULL,nrow=1))
```

Comment: This is an alternative solution